# Drawing lines using \foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw, tikz-calc

I'd like to get a picture similar to that uploaded below. Basically, I'm trying to add perpendicular lines to every ray on the positive orthant. This is my attempt, could you tell me what is wrong in the code? The problem is, obviously, with the perpendicular lines, where I get the following error: !Package pgf error: No shape named 1 is known. Thank you in advance, because you are really helping me a lot. 
[image]

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc} 

    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={circle,inner sep=1pt,fill,label={#1},name=#1},
      extended line/.style={shorten >=-#1,shorten <=-#1},
      extended line/.default=1cm]

    \draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (4.5,0) node[anchor=north west] {\small Security 1};
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (0,4.5) node[anchor=south east] {\small Security 2};

    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (2.5,3);

        \foreach \x [count=\xi] in {15,45,75} {
            \draw[->](0,0)--(\x:3.5);
            \node at (\x:3.9){$x_{.\xi}$};
            \draw ($(\xi)!3cm!270:(A)$) -- ($(\xi)!4cm!90:(A)$);
         }

      \end{tikzpicture}
      \end{document}
```

Also, how can I tell the code to hide the line perpendicular to the second ray?

Comment: To reference a node, you need to give it a name: `\node (\xi) at....`. (Do not include `thank you` in your post - it is always implied - not necessary)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Marmot, he accomplishes a number of improvements, leaving the syntax closer to what the OP had proposed, and achieving conditionals by way of `sign`, etc.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={circle,inner sep=1pt,fill,label={#1},name=#1},
  extended line/.style={shorten >=-#1,shorten <=-#1},
  extended line/.default=1cm]

\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (4.5,0) node[anchor=north west] {\small Security 1};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (0,4.5) node[anchor=south east] {\small Security 2};

\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (2.5,3);

\foreach \x [count=\xi] in {15,45,75} { 
  \draw[->](0,0)--(\x:3.5) coordinate (\xi); 
  \node at (\x:3.9){$x_{.\xi}$}; 
  \draw (A) -- ($(A)!{sign(45-\x)*3.5cm}!90:(\xi)$); 
}
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={circle,inner sep=1pt,fill,label={#1},name=#1},
  extended line/.style={shorten >=-#1,shorten <=-#1},
  extended line/.default=1cm]

\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (4.5,0) node[anchor=north west] {\small Security 1};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (0,4.5) node[anchor=south east] {\small Security 2};

\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (2.5,3);

    \foreach \x [count=\xi] in {15,45,75} {
        \draw[->](0,0)--(\x:3.5);
        \node at (\x:3.9){$x_{.\xi}$};
        \ifnum\x<45\relax\draw[-](0,0)--(\the\numexpr\x+90\relax:3.5);\fi
        \ifnum\x>45\relax\draw[-](0,0)--(\the\numexpr\x-90\relax:3.5);\fi
     }
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Steven! What was wrong in my code?

Comment: @Nenne I am not a `tikz` expert, and did not recognize the syntax `\draw ($(\xi)!3cm!270:(A)$) -- ($(\xi)!4cm!90:(A)$);`  But I also knew you would require conditionals in order to draw the perpendicular rightward, leftward, or not at all.

Comment: @marmot I thank you for helping me, though I don't think that is the result the OP wants, since it: 1) draws perpendiculars to the 45deg line, and 2) extends the perpendicular both rightward and leftward from the origin.

Comment: Thank you @marmot.  Now I can take the opportunity to try to understand this new (to me) syntax.

Comment: OK, next step: use `\foreach \x [count=\xi] in {15,45,75} { 
  \draw[<-](\x:3.5) coordinate[label=\x:$x_{.\xi}$] (\xi)
  -- (A) -- ($(A)!{sign(45-\x)*3.5cm}!90:(\xi)$); 
}`, which is shorter ;-)

Comment: @marmot Sorry.  Heading out **this moment** for the long weekend.

Comment: @marmot: just for curiosity, if I want to add a vector starting at the origin which coincides with the first ray x1, what is the right way to do it? this should be done inside the \foreach or after?

Comment: @Nenne You already have these vectors: `\draw[->](0,0)--(<angle>:<radius>);`.

Comment: yes, you're right... everything still seems so difficult for me!

Comment: @marmot: sorry to bother you again, may I ask you also what is the most efficient way to draw the arc in this case?

Comment: @Nenne `\draw (-15:1) arc (-15:105:1);` but it doesn't hurt to ask new questions.